# Client Socket not getting reponse bytes in .NET

Tags: c#, sockets

I am creating and sending a message on server socket and not getting any response in return , I would like to know what could be possible reasons for the same. Below is my sample code for client socket

```
static void Main()
{
    int _DCPport = 9090;
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("HostName");
    Console.WriteLine("Got the IP Host Info" , ipHostInfo.ToString ());
    IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
    Console.WriteLine("Got the IP hadress Info");

    //End point of the host where the socket will be connected
    IPEndPoint remoteDAPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, _DCPport);

    // Create a clientSocket that connects to host
    Socket clientDAP = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    clientDAP.Connect(remoteDAPEndPoint);
    Console.WriteLine("Client socket connected to remote end point");

    #region Input variables
    string requestString = "Hello";
    string responseString = "";

    byte[] requestByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);
    byte[] responseByte = new byte[1024];

    StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int byteResult = 0;
    #endregion

    try
    {
        //sending the string as bytes over the socket
        Console.WriteLine("Sending the input " + requestString);
        clientDAP.Send(requestByte);
    }
    catch (SocketException eX)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(eX.Message);
    }

    try
    {
        //recieving the response bytes
        byteResult = clientDAP.Receive(responseByte, clientDAP.Available, SocketFlags.None);
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved {0} bytes as response from remote end point" , byteResult);
        if (clientDAP.Connected)
        {
            responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseByte);
            messageBuilder.Append(responseString);
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException eX)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(eX.Message);
    }

    clientDAP.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    clientDAP.Disconnect(true);


    string sResult = messageBuilder.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(sResult);


}
```

I am not getting any bytes when i call socket.Recieve() , Any reasons why such is happening ?

Comment: Did you code the server also? It would help to have a *complete* example to try to reason about (E.g. a [MCVE]). Beyond your `Receive`, your code is broken (assumes that the entire `responseByte` buffer is valid when calling `GetString`, rather than using `byteResult`), is it possible the server has similar issues?

Comment: @-damien_The_Unbeliever : No i didnt have controll on server.Also The code you mentioed is broken i accept it . but if you see byteResult = clientDAP.Receive(responseByte); byteResult itself is coming 0. I tried with telnet request/response i am getting the proper output.

Answer (score 1):

From [`Socket.Send`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w93yy28a(v=vs.110).aspx):

> There is also no guarantee that the data you send will appear on the network immediately. To increase network efficiency, the underlying system may delay transmission until a significant amount of outgoing data is collected. A successful completion of the Send method means that the underlying system has had room to buffer your data for a network send

Which means that the data may not have even arrived at the server yet when your call to `Send` has completed. Let alone that the server has had time to process your data and return a response.

And yet your code charges straight ahead to try to receive the server's response. This isn't unreasonable, in and of itself. Your call to [`Receive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26f591ax(v=vs.110).aspx) *would* have blocked until it had received *some* data *if* you had specified the size of your buffer, rather than using [`Available`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.available(v=vs.110).aspx), which will happily return `0` if there's no data yet available. So your `Receive` call is asking for up to `0` bytes and that's how many you're being given.

So change this line

```
byteResult = clientDAP.Receive(responseByte, 1024, SocketFlags.None);
```

(Or better yet, introduce a constant and/or use `responseByte.Length` or switch to an overload where you don't explicitly specify how  many bytes you want)

Comment: Agreed , I did the same. but still no reponse , I think i need to check the server side code as well, because i tried to do the same with telnet and when i sent my request , i  got the response in a go. So could be something is happening on server side like closiong of server socket till the time i recieve whole bytes or something equivalent

Comment: @Anamay if its telnet-like, maybe it's expecting you to send complete lines, i.e. include a `\n` at the end of your string?

Comment: The request i am sending is a xml , converting it into bytes and then sending over network The thing which amazed me is : on sending the request in improper format say missing end tag of xml , i am getting response from host socket as my request is ot a valid xml.But when i send xml properly formatted like without line breaks and spaces i am getting 0 byte as recieved.